# Windows Workflow Foundation WF4 - Handling multiple worklfows in single service

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I would like to create a application which can be used by different teams present in my organization for automate the process they are following in there day to day activities.

My application will have Client-Server-Database. It should provide the following features.

- User must be able to run different workflows, and multiple instances of the same workflows with a different context (different data/business objects).
- Some workflows will be long-running, involve multiple users/client session and waiting for external user input. So the workflows must be able to be persisted and respond to some signal from a client.
- All the workflow execution should be done in the server only. Client will just shows the current workflow execution progress.

The problem here is, There is no common workflow followed by all the teams. Each team has its own workflow. Some teams can have multiple workflows based on role or task they are performing. I don't want to have multiple workflow services for each workflow. I just want to create a single WCF service which can handle different request from different team, and based on the request it has to start the appropriate workflow in server.

Any suggestion for developing this application by using Workflow Foundation?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by having loose-XAML definitions of your workflows, which are stored in a database. Your WCF service can use `XamlActivityServices` for hydrating (and also saving) a XAML file at run time and launch the workflow.

Check out this link for additional details on how to go about working with XAML-based workflows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  I have another one doubt. How do I persist the execution to the database from client side. The client will not know about the database which is used by the server.